# Azure AD groups and permissions

Tags: azure, grafana

I would like to know what AD Groups from a "ResourceGroup" and "PeopleSearch" require access to Grafana, and at what role each group needs access.

Had a look at Microsoft Graph but not what I need.

Is this possible? I have searched but I don't find any solutions.

Comment: That depends on the Grafana configuration. Please provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this issue on my own.

Due to additional details in the screenshot I won't be able to share it but feel free to ask me for additional details.

Thanks.